# Orthogonal Matrix 4

Tags: matrices

Let $M_{32}$ be vector space with inner product of $AB$ given by $\text{tr}(B^TA)$.

The question is to find a non-zero matrix B orthogonal to
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Any hints as to how I can start this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I did try the Gram-Smichdt process however I got the determinant as equal to zero after working out the cofactors. So yeah no luck.

Comment: Let $B=\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr e&f\cr}$, calculate the trace of $B^tA$, set it equal to zero, and find a nonzero solution.

Comment: So why are you posting the same problem twice?

Comment: Three times, actually.

Comment: @Arghya, I don't know whether before, or after, but the same problem has been posted more than once.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all "clever" but the obvious thing to do is to take a matrix $B= \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \\ e & f\end{bmatrix}$ so that $B^TA= \begin{bmatrix}a & c & e \\ b & d & f\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}a+ 3c+ 5e  & 2a+ 4c+ 6e \\ b+ 3d+ 5f & 2b+ 4d+ 6f \end{bmatrix}$.

The trace of that is a+ 3c+ 5e+ 2b+ 4d+ 6f.  Choose a, b, c, d, e, and f so that is equal to 0.  There exist an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take a matrix 
$$ B = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d \\ 
e & f
\end{array}
 \right],$$ and compute the product $B^T A$, then $tr(B^TA)$.